# Cannot update intel microcode using apt-get

Tags: debian, kernel, firmware

I'm using Debian Stretch, kernel 4.17.11  and when I run

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

I get

> Package intel-microcode is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro added

Answer (score 4):

You are not finding the package `intel-microcode`, because it is on the `non-free` repositories, that are not added by default on installation time.

You need to add it to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

As in:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free 
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

Do not forget to run `sudo apt update` *after* adding the non-free repository and *before* running `sudo apt install`.

> Package: intel-microcode (3.20180425.1~deb9u1) [non-free]
>
> Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs
>
> This package contains updated system processor microcode for Intel
>   i686 and Intel X86-64 processors. Intel releases microcode updates to
>   correct processor behavior as documented in the respective processor
>   specification updates.
>
> For AMD processors, please refer to the amd64-microcode package.